# Solve the phase plane equation to obtain the integral curves for the system:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the phase plane equation to obtain the integral curves for the system:

$$\begin{align*}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}&=2y-x\\\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}&=e^x+y\end{align*}$$

It's for a 200 level paper; differential equations. What is important with this question is that it is non-linear. So he can't use linear methods. He will try a Jacobian matrix and see if that gives anything useful. His textbook also says he could maybe change it into polar coordinates, but that doesn't seem to be helping.

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/system/nonlinear/linearization/linearization.html

Comment: The references to "him" no longer make sense after you edited out your boyfriend.

Answer (score 1):

The phase plane equation for the integral curves is

$$\def\part#1#2{\frac{\mathrm d#1}{\mathrm d#2}}
\part yx=\frac{\part yt}{\part xt}=\frac{\mathrm e^x+y}{2y-x}\;.$$

To get a grip on this, it helps to expand around the equilibrium. At equilibrium, $\part xt=2y-x=0$, and thus $y=x/2$, so we can write $y=x/2+z$, with $y'=1/2+z'$. Substituting this into the differential equation for $y$ yields

$$
\begin{align}
\frac12+z'
&=\frac{\mathrm e^x+\frac x2+z}{2(\frac x2 + z)-x}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm e^x+\frac x2+z}{2z}\;,\\
z'
&=\frac{\mathrm e^x+\frac x2}{2z}\;,\\
2zz'
&=\mathrm e^x+\frac x2\;,\\
z^2
&=\mathrm e^x+\frac {x^2}4+C\;,\\
z
&=\pm\sqrt{\mathrm e^x+\frac {x^2}4+C}\;,\\
y
&=\frac x2\pm\sqrt{\mathrm e^x+\frac {x^2}4+C}\;.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I follow until your last sentence. What is the resulting differential equation for $z$? (More specifically, how do we see $e^x+y$ solely as a function of $z$?)

Comment: @anon: I'd written this out but then removed it because I saw the question is on homework; I'll write it out again.

Comment: Oh, of course. For some reason I was thinking we had to get it autonomous in $z$, not sure why I thought that. Moment of brain seepage.

Comment: Thanks.
This was posted by my gf on my behalf. This is exactly what i needed. Knew it would be something simple!